# Way of white circlet

Tags: ps4, dark-souls-3

In dark souls 3 I am having trouble seeing summon signs. I have tried using the "way of white" circlet but it won't allow me to use it. I haven't been logging out while being invaded or anything like that. Does anybody know how to activate the circlet or something? Because I've tried using an ember and it still won't work

Comment: It's probably not activating because you haven't done anything wrong. There's probably something else interfering with your ability to see summon signs. What's your soul level, hollowing, and the location you're attempting to see summon signs?

Comment: And when you say you tried using an ember, do you mean to activate the circlet, or to see summon signs? Because you can only see summon signs if you're embered (or use the Seek Guidance" miracle).

Comment: I used the ember to try to see summon signs. my level is like 37. I am pretty new to the game so I don't have any hollowing. I usually try to summon at the dilapidated bridge.

Comment: Are you able to see player messages? How about invading or putting down your own summon sign? Just want to make sure the the other online functionalities aren't also messed up.

Comment: yeah I can see messages and my summon sign is working

Comment: I mean my soapstone is working

Comment: Okay, one more sanity check -- no password in the game's network settings? Other than that, I'm at a loss... The only thing I can think of is that since it's not a boss door, there may not be any summon signs there. Do you not see any signs in front of Vordt's boss room? Sorry to keep asking questions; just want to rule out all other possibilities.

Comment: And you have PS+, correct?

Comment: I don't think there is a password. btw I don't see summon signs anywhere. it's really strange. Thanks though I'll try to get to the bottom of this. Thanks for the help

Comment: I have plus yeah

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use the **Way of White Circlet**, that means that you haven't disconnected while invaded or while invading, you don't have to worry about that. If you did, you could use the Circlet. Anyway, try this:

First of all, be sure that your Ps4 is connected to the internet. Next check that your game is updated and playing in Online mode.

After checking all of this, let's see the in-game factors. DS3 matchmaking depends on your **Soul Level** and your **maximum weapon upgrade**, so for example, although you are SL 37, if your highest weapon upgrade is +6, you won't get paired with someone that has a +10 weapon. The location is also an important factor, if you are overleveled for an early area, you will find troubles seeing summon signs, and on the contrary, if you don't level up too much and go through the game. If you are embered you will usually see some NPC summon signs.

PS: Referring to pushasha's comment, hollowing does not make any difference on seeing summon signs.

Comment: Yeah, I'm at 99 hollowing and don't have issues summoning, I was just curious as I had heard some weird rumors about the dark sigils affecting summons, but those all seem to be unfounded.

Comment: additionally, white sign soapstones are not visible if you've already killed the boss in the area

Comment: thanks guys! It might just be that I'm overleveled for where I'm at. This is some good stuff. you have been really helpful.

Comment: @Kritner Didn't know that! Thanks for the info.

Comment: @CalebStewart if my answer did really help you, please accept it